# How do I do an external method call for a method in another class in Java? The method that is trying to be called is a method that uses a Hashmap

Tags: java, methods, syntax

//This is the name of the method. The method designed to read information from a text file that is stored outside of the programme. The method is contained inside of a class called FileHelper. This class conatins Various other methods to help with the tasks of reading and writing of files that are based outside the programme.

```
public HashMap<String, String> readAMap (String filename)  {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String word;
        word = reader.readLine();
        while(word != null) {
            String response = reader.readLine();
            if(response != null) {
                response = response.trim();
                if(response.length() != 0) {
                    map.put(word, response);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Blank response for " +
                                       word + " in file " +
                                       filename);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Missing response for " +
                                   word + " in file " +
                                   filename);
            }
            word = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem reading file: " + filename +
                           " in readAMap");
    }
    return map;
}
```

//This is the method I'm using to call the above method this method is another class.

```
private void fileResponseMap()
{
   FileResponseMap = FileHelper.HashMap<String, String>readAMap(JavaFile);
   return FileResponseMap;
 }
}
```

//I'm trying to r

Comment: Please put just a little more effort into the asking of your question. Explain the code, explain your problem, give us a little help please.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `readAMap` is not static, therefore it cannot be accessed in the way way you try it in `fileResponseMap`.

Either you can declare it static:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> readAMap (String filename) {
...
```

Or in the calling method you create an instance of `FileHelper` and call the instance method on that:

```
private HashMap<String, String> fileResponseMap()
{
   FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
   return fileHelper.readAMap(JavaFile);

}
```

You must also define your return type when you return the HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

- Instanciate the class offering the `readMap` method.
- Call the method on the instance

---

```
class Foo {
   public HashMap<String, String> readAMap(String filename) {
      // ...
   }
}

private HashMap<String, String> fileResponseMap() {
   Foo foo = new Foo();

   String javaFile = "my-java-file.txt";
   HashMap<String, String> map = foo.readAMap(javaFile);

   return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your method from here should be do this:
Before all thing instance your class ex: his name is `FileResponseMap` like:

```
 FileResponseMap ycn = new FileResponseMap();
```

And call your method like this:

```
 `ycn.readAMap ("JavaFile");`.
```

And you have method called with return `HashMap<String, String>`.

```
private HashMap<String, String> fileResponseMap()
     {
        FileResponseMap ycn = new FileResponseMap();
         HashMap<String, String> hmfile =  ycn.readAMap("JavaFile");

     return hmfile ;
    }
}
```